# ReactJS with Django Framework Vercel deployment failing

Tags: python, reactjs, vercel

[here error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoTwQ.png)
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6OaW.png)

error: spawn pip3 enoent

My existing project on react js with backend django, both are same repo. I've to deploy on vercel but crashing on build time.

want to Vercel link successfully deployed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated above image